# Comparison between a string and an element of an array of strings

Tags: java, string, immutability

Part of my code:

```
  int t,w;
  String day;
  String[] week=new String[]{"mon","tues","wed","thurs","fri","sat","sun"};
  .
  .
  .
  day=sc.nextLine();
  .
  .
   for(i=0;i<7;i++)
   {
           if(day.equals(week[i]))
           {

                break;
           }
    }
```

the '.equals()' method is returning 'false' every time even if the string contain is same.The output does not alter with the initialization of the array.e.g. 'String[] week={"mon","tues",......}' gives same output.Does this method return false when memory location is different?Please clarify.

Comment: day=sc.nextString().trim();

Comment: sc.nextString().trim() is not working and showing "error: cannot find symbol
                day=sc.nextString().trim();
                      ^
  symbol:   method nextString()"
but sc.nextLine().trim() did the job.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ankush below works fine for me, make sure ur using same case for this code. if u want to match any case use **equalsIgnoreCase** instead of **equals**

```
package com.java;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    static void check() {
        String day;
        String[] week = new String[] { "mon", "tues", "wed", "thurs", "fri", "sat", "sun" };

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        day = sc.nextLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            if (day.equals(week[i])) {
                System.out.println("break");
                break;
            }
        }

        sc.close();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Test.check();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is sc.close()  significant?One more query: are the elements of the array immutable object?

Comment: @AnkushPandit, yes it's always good to close the scanner since its an IO operation......... Regarding your 2nd query, The Strings contained in the String[] are indeed immutable, but the array is mutable. It might be an array of immutable types, but the array itself is mutable. Meaning you can set those references to anything you want.

Comment: Yes it did.Thanks @Kumar

Comment: @AnkushPandit great. If you feel that my answer helped you, you can 
 accept it [http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `scanner.nextLine()` you are reading more than the entered string. You are also reading in the EOL. Try to debug this and see which string is actually contained in the "day" variable.

Comment: One interesting observation: I was trying the 'compareTo()' method and every time it was showing the same results no matter what  my input is.Any explanation?

Comment: While printing the value of  'day' ,I found no difference.But then I put the value of 'day' manually instead of using scanner class and get the desired output.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read only one word from scanner, but after that you need to clear new line character that you typed at the end of your input with pressing "Enter“:

```
int t,w;
String day;
String[] week = new String[] {"mon","tues","wed","thurs","fri","sat","sun"};

 . . . 

day = sc.next();
 . . 
for (i = 0; i < week.length; i++) {
    if(day.equalsIgnoreCase(week[i])) {
        break;
    }
}
sc.nextLine(); // here you get rid of remaining new line character
sc.close();
```